# Discord.js presence user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm not sure on what to put in for user as I'm getting the error:

`Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

My target is to have the status of my admin be in a VC channel name just like Stat bot.

[PICTURE IN VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RGg7.png)

```
{
    let user = 7262235XXXXX921660
    let statusUser = user.presence.status
    client.channels.cache.get("7881455XXXXX434389").setName(Admins Status: statusUser); //its a voice channel

    setTimeout(refreshData, 10*1000);
}
```

Comment: `user` is a number, it does not have a `presence` property.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if your problem is solved but you can try

```js
// Get Server
const guild = await client.guild.cache.get("ID")
//Get user
const user = await guild.members.cache.get("ID here also")
//get presence
const presence = user.presence.status
```

Keep in mind to use this in a async function and also presence isn't stored per user, it is something present in the guild members cache. If you try to get a user presence only it will return undefined.
andddd you need intents enabled (both) which you can find in the dev portal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get user by using client.

V11:

```
let user = client.fetchUser("7262235XXXXX921660")
let statusUser = user.presence.status
```

V12:

```
let user = client.users.fetch("7262235XXXXX921660")
let statusUser = user.presence.status
```

Then you can get presence of user.

Comment: client.fetchUser is not a function

Comment: @Ariagatang can you try client.users.fetch('7262235XXXXX921660')

Comment: still no luck just cannot read property 'status'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would make sure you have the presence intent enabled for your bot in your Discord applications home menu. You need the presence intent to receive presence event data.

Then, fetch the user. In your case, you could just replace your current user variable with `let user = client.fetchUser("theiruserid")`

Comment: TypeError: client.fetchUser is not a function